# pd.read_csv parsing incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Date,Time,Mood,Tags,Medications,Notes
"Jul 25, 2018",9:41 PM,8,,,"",
"Jul 26, 2018",10:05 AM,4,,,"",
"Jul 26, 2018",12:00 PM,3,,,"",
"Jul 26, 2018",7:00 PM,8,,,"",
"Jul 27, 2018",12:01 PM,8,,,"",
```

I run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./data/MoodLog_2018_09_14.csv", 
                 dtype={'Date': str, 'Time': str, 'Mood': str, 'Tags': str, 
                        'Medications': str, 'Notes': str})

print(df['Time'].head(5))
```

and it prints the following:

```
Jul 25, 2018    8
Jul 26, 2018    4
Jul 26, 2018    3
Jul 26, 2018    8
Jul 27, 2018    8
Name: Time, dtype: object
```

It's including the `Mood` column in the `Time` column.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your rows having a trailing `,`, while the header does not. Change the header to: 
`Date,Time,Mood,Tags,Medications,Notes,`, and you will get an extra column which you can then drop.

#### Input: `test.csv`

```
Date,Time,Mood,Tags,Medications,Notes,
"Jul 25, 2018",9:41 PM,8,,,"",
"Jul 26, 2018",10:05 AM,4,,,"",
"Jul 26, 2018",12:00 PM,3,,,"",
"Jul 26, 2018",7:00 PM,8,,,"",
"Jul 27, 2018",12:01 PM,8,,,"",
```

#### Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", 
                 dtype={'Date': str, 'Time': str, 'Mood': str, 'Tags': str, 
                        'Medications': str, 'Notes': str}).iloc[:, :-1]
```

#### Output: `df`

```
           Date      Time Mood Tags Medications Notes
0  Jul 25, 2018   9:41 PM    8  NaN         NaN   NaN
1  Jul 26, 2018  10:05 AM    4  NaN         NaN   NaN
2  Jul 26, 2018  12:00 PM    3  NaN         NaN   NaN
3  Jul 26, 2018   7:00 PM    8  NaN         NaN   NaN
4  Jul 27, 2018  12:01 PM    8  NaN         NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Hmmmm, not sure why that would be? I added the exact .csv I used

Comment: Because I didn't notice that you changed the csv.